# Why is the java compiler complaining about StringBuffer

Tags: java

It is showing a compile error at `method("shruthi")` and moreover compiler is giving warning to convert the `StringBuffer` to String at static method.
If I replace `StringBuffer` with `String` it works fine. But I want to know about `StringBuffer`. Please explain why that doesn't work.

```
public class Test13{
    public static void method1(String s){
          System.out.println("String Version");
    }
    public static void method(StringBuffer sb){
         System.out.println("String Buffer Version");
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
          method1("null");
          method("shruthi");
    }
}
```

Comment: `"shruthi"` is a `String`.  You're trying to pass it to something expecting a `StringBuffer`.  What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood how `string buffer` works and you don't initialize it anywhere, nor do you append to it.

```
public class Demo
{
    public static StringBuffer sBuffer;

    public static void appendString(String str)
    {
        sBuffer.append(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        sBuffer = new StringBuffer(" test");
        appendString(" adding this");
        System.out.print(sBuffer);
    }
}
```

Look at the [doc's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) on how to initialize and use it.

**OUTPUT**

```
 test adding this
```

Answer (score 4):

You defined a method with the signature `method(StringBuffer)` but you are calling it by `method("shruthi");`

**The error is:**

`method(StringBuffer)` is expecting a `StringBuffer` object as parameter, you are passing instead a String ...

That is a reason for the compiler to complain.

Comment: That's semi right and wrong, it's not excepting a string buffer object. You're supposed to use String but it's with the built in `append` function and not directly throwing strings in.